# Pythonic way to find duplicate and unique values in a list of dictonaries

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list of dictonaries:

```
[
{'name' : 'product a', 'sku': 'p100', 'price: 1.2},
{'name' : 'product x', 'sku': 'p120', 'price: 1.3},
{'name' : 'product x', 'sku': 'p100', 'price: 2.2},
{'name' : 'product a', 'sku': 'p100', 'price: 4.1}, 
{'name' : 'product a', 'sku': 'p20', 'price: 1.3},
{'name' : 'product a', 'sku': 'p20', 'price: 2.2}]
```

And I want to find duplicate and unique values of sku and return them as two new lists. (Duplicate in my case means 3 or more times. Triplicate)

This is a working solution:

```
def find_dict_duplicates(lines, key, times=2):
    duplicate = [] 
    unique = []
    for line in lines:
        count = 0
        for l in lines:
            if line[key] == l[key]:
                count += 1
        if count > times:
            duplicates.append(line)
        else:
            unique.append(line)
return duplicate, unique
```

Results:

```
duplicates =
[
{'name' : 'product a', 'sku': 'p100', 'price: 1.2},
{'name' : 'product a', 'sku': 'p100', 'price: 2.2},
{'name' : 'product a', 'sku': 'p100', 'price: 4.1}]

unique =
[
{'name' : 'product a', 'sku': 'p120', 'price: 1.3},
{'name' : 'product a', 'sku': 'p20', 'price: 1.3},
{'name' : 'product a', 'sku': 'p20', 'price: 2.2}]    # The critiria is more than 2 times to be consider duplicate so this is correct
```

But is super slow and ugly.
Is slow because if a list contains 50.000 products then the comparison needed is 50.000^2 = 2.500.000.000 (5+ minutes waiting)
And ugly since this is more like c than python.

Can you sudgest a better way?

Comment: If you have any control over the format of the input data, consider changing it to a dict from `sku` value to list of dicts, then the actual task is as trivial as checking the `len` of each value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: After Getting Rid of Threading it's even faster

Because There's alot going on I recommend First Trying to figure out what's happening by visualizing in a debugger

```py
def find_dict_duplicates(lines, key, times=2):
    duplicate = []
    unique = []
    added_values = {}

    def add_to_list(add_into, index_of_items_to_add):
        for ind in index_of_items_to_add:
            add_into.append(lines[ind])

    # Loops Through All The lines and saves Them with their index and Value
    values = {ind: line[key] for ind, line in enumerate(lines)}

    # Loops Through the index and values line by line created above
    for ind, val in values.items():
        # Adds the current Index to the added_values dict
        # and stores them like this item: [indexes]

        if val not in added_values:
            added_values[val] = [ind]

        # If the item was already added in the dict we just append the new index to it
        else:
            added_values[val].append(ind)

    # Now loops Through all The Indexes Created By Above Loop
    for item in added_values.values():
        if len(item) > times:
            list_to_add_to = duplicate

        else:
            list_to_add_to = unique

        # Does some checking above and Adds the current Item to the correct dictionary
        add_to_list(list_to_add_to, item)

    return duplicate, unique
```

Comment: I was a bit worried seeing the thread library since the machine executing the code was an old dual-core laptop, but i was pleasantly surprised that this was ~10 times faster even in that old machine and learned a trick or two.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the dictionary once and maintain another dictionary which stores count of each value. Then you can use the count dictionary to get the unique and duplicate entries. Its complexity is O(n).